# pyspark Model interpretation from pipeline model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib

I am implementing DecisionTreeClassifier in pyspark using the Pipeline module as I have several feature engineering steps to perform on my dataset. 
The code is similar to the example from Spark documentation:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

# Load the data stored in LIBSVM format as a DataFrame.
data = sqlContext.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

# Index labels, adding metadata to the label column.
# Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index.
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)
# Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
# We specify maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
featureIndexer =\
    VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=4).fit(data)

# Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

# Train a DecisionTree model.
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol="indexedFeatures")

# Chain indexers and tree in a Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[labelIndexer, featureIndexer, dt])

# Train model.  This also runs the indexers.
model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

# Make predictions.
predictions = model.transform(testData)

# Select example rows to display.
predictions.select("prediction", "indexedLabel", "features").show(5)

# Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
    labelCol="indexedLabel", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="precision")
accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Test Error = %g " % (1.0 - accuracy))

treeModel = model.stages[2]
# summary only
print(treeModel)
```

The question is how do I perform the model interpretation on this? The pipeline model object does not have the method **toDebugString()** similar to the method in the **DecisionTree.trainClassifier** class
And I cannot use the **DecisionTree.trainClassifier** in my pipeline because the trainclassifier() takes the training data as a parameter.

Whereas the pipeline accepts the training data as an argument in the **fit()** method and **transform()** on the test data

Is there a way to use the pipeline and still perform the model interpretation & find attribute importance?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have used the method below in almost all my model interpretations in pyspark. The line below uses the naming conventions from your code excerpt.

```
dtm = model.stages[-1] # you estimator is the last stage in the pipeline
# hence the DecisionTreeClassifierModel will be the last transformer in the PipelineModel object 
dtm.explainParams()
```

Now you have access to all the methods of the DecisionTreeClassifierModel. All the available methods and attributes can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifierModel). Code was not tested on your example.

Comment: Note that in a similar but more convoluted fashion, one can extract the estimator's model from a CrossValidatorModel's best model as well.